# How to use different using libraries for different platforms in a PCL project since Xamarin PCL do not allow the usage of #If directives

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

I would like to do something like

```
    #if __IOS__
    using System.Drawing;
    using UIKit;
    using CoreGraphics;
    #endif

     #if __ANDROID__
     using Android.Graphics;
     #endif
```

but since the #if directive is not allowed in a PCL, and I cant seem to do a

```
 if  (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
{ 
using System.Drawing;
using UIKit;
using CoreGraphics;
}
else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android){
        using Android.Graphics;
}
```

as these declarations cannot be done in a namespace, I am wondering if there are any other methods that I can use to achieve my objective in a PCL project using Xamarin forms.

I'm new to C# and Xamarin forms so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can not do that in a PCL project/library, look at using a shared project if you are trying to code platform-specific via #if/#endif:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/code-sharing/ Otherwise you would need to create platform-specific libraries to access the frameworks of those platforms.